# Getting rid of "stdin: is not a tty" with remote command execution through ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, login, remote

The problem is with a Debian Jessie server.

I run a remote command with ssh like the following example.

```
#! /bin/bash
ssh root@srv01  << 'STOP_SERVER'
    touch /tmp/testFile
STOP_SERVER
```

This works except that I get a lot of output that I don’t want. Here is an example with sensible  information replaced by stars.

```
root@home:~# ./test.sh
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Linux srv01.***.*** 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #5 SMP Wed Sep 9 17:24:34 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux

server    : ***
ip        : ***
hostname  : srv01.***.***

stdin: is not a tty
```

If I change the script to the following

```
#! /bin/bash
ssh root@srv01  << 'STOP_SERVER' >> /dev/null
    touch /tmp/testFile
STOP_SERVER
```

I get the following output

```
root@home:~# ./test.sh
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
stdin: is not a tty
```

If I add the option -q to the ssh command I get

```
root@home:~# ./test.sh
stdin: is not a tty
```

And this is where I’m stuck because I don’t know how to rewove `stdin: is not a tty`.

I wish I could avoid output redirect to /dev/null. It’s just the login messages that I don’t want to see.

Comment: What happens if you use `ssh -t`?

Comment: @glennjackman there is no difference in the output when -t is added as option of ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a fix.

Instead of writing

```
#! /bin/bash
ssh root@srv01  << 'STOP_SERVER'
    date
    touch /tmp/testFile
STOP_SERVER
```

write the following

```
#! /bin/bash
ssh root@srv01  '
date
touch /tmp/testFile
'
```

No problems anymore.

Comment: Also take a look at the `-t` option for `ssh`.

Comment: @AndyDalton option -t doesn't change the output

Comment: Note that those two snippets do slightly different things: the first runs a remote _login_, non-interactive shell, while the second runs a remote _non-login_, non-interactive shell (i.e. doesn't source `.bash_profile` or `.profile` or whatever is applicable, also depending on the remote user's default shell). Hence, the environments your commands are run in will likely differ in the two cases. The "stdin: is not a tty" message seems to be printed by your remote shell's initialization file; an alternative way to prevent it from being sourced is `ssh user@host bash -s <<EOT ...`.

Comment: @fra-san how do you explain that the `>> /dev/null` hides everything except the stdin line ?

Comment: `>>/dev/null` redirects standard input on the local side. "stdin: is not a tty" is probably printed to standard error (on the remote host and, consequently, by the local `ssh` as well), `>/dev/null 2>&1` should let you get rid of it.